# Проверка работы службы (Service) в системе Android

Tags: android, java, service

Здравствуйте. Пишу приложение под *Android*, обобщенная структура которого - главная *Actvity* (плюс куча дочерних Activity, но не особо относится к вопросу) и класс, наследующий службу (Service). По нажатии кнопки в глав. *Activity* данный наследник службы запускается и выполняет фоново некие предписанные ему задачи.

Два вопроса:

а) по закрытии *Activity*, моя служба продолжает автономно работать и дальше?

б) если а) = true, то как из под запущенной позже (снова) в некий момент времени главной *Activity* определить, работает ли данная служба в системе или нет?

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> rs = am.getRunningServices(50);

 for (int i=0; i<rs.size(); i++) {
   ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo
   rsi = rs.get(i);
   Log.i("Service", "Process " + rsi.process + " with component " + rsi.service.getClassName());
 }
```

Этот кусок кода в моей *Activity* выполнит то, что мне надо. В цикле просто сравниваем просматриваемый класс службы с нашей и далее поступаем, как и задумывали по логике.

Answer (score 1):

Посылайте интент сервису через `startService(intent)` и если сервис запущен то выполнение сервиса будет продолжено. Иначе он стартанет сервис по новой. Т.е. вам не нужно проверять запущен сервис или нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Как вариант. Но, понимаете, нужно сразу по запуску определить, работает она уже или нет и просто заблокировать кнопку (это принципиально в данном случае для меня), по клику которой активируется служба. Или предлагаете намеренно вызвать в самом начале startService(...)? Как тогда и в таком случае определить, она уже работает или еще не была запущена?

Answer (score 1):

а) True

б) Вставьте в onCreate/onDestroy сервиса сеттер флага показывающего жизнеспособность сервиса. Далее чтобы понять жив сервис или нет достаточно проверить значение флага